# Using named_scope through associations

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I try to optimize some queries (Rails 2.3.18)

Here is my test case :

```
class Post
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  named_scope :public, :conditions => ["#{Post.table_name}.public = ?", true]
  named_scope :of_user, lambda {|u|
    { :conditions => ["#{Post.table_name}.user_id = ?", u] }
  }
end

class Category
  has_many :posts
end

class User
  has_many :posts
end
```

My query is simple : obtain all the categories having a public posts of a user.

```
def categories
  Post.of_user(u).public.map(&:category)
end

SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.user_id = 123 AND posts.public = 1
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id = 4
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id = 5
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id = 6
```

We now have 1 query for posts, and n queries for each category.
We can be more efficient using `:include` :

```
def categories
  Post.of_user(u).public.find(:all, :include => :category).map(&:category)
end

SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.user_id = 123 AND posts.public = 1
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id IN (4,5,6)
```

Now, we have only 2 queries : one for posts, one for categories.
We can be more efficient using `proxy_options` :

```
def categories
  proxy_options = Post.of_user(u).public.proxy_options
  # Returns { :conditions => "posts.user_id = 123 AND posts.public = 1" }
  proxy_options[:joins] = "INNER JOIN #{Post.table_name}
      ON #{Post.table_name}.category_id = #{Category.table_name}.id"
  return Category.find(:all, proxy_options)
end

SELECT * FROM categories INNER JOIN posts ON posts.category_id = category.id
  WHERE posts.user_id = 123 AND posts.public = 1
```

It works, I have only 1 query, but I find this method "ugly".

Do you have any other method for **"Using named_scope through associations"** ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would probably use

```
class User
  has_many :posts
  has_many :categories, :through => :posts
end
```

And you don't need any named_scope to get user's categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another association and let Rails handle the sql query for you.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :public_posts, :class_name => 'Post', :conditions => { :public => true }
  has_many :public_post_categories, :through => :public_posts, :source => :category
end
```

Using this, you can just call `User.public_post_categories`.